# Como fazer coleta de dados em web scrapping no Python?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

Dentro [desta URL](https://s3.amazonaws.com/video.udacity-data.com/topher/2018/November/5bf32290_turnstile/turnstile.html), tem vários links , tenho que pegar os links referentes ao mês de junho de 2017, fazer download deles e criar um dataframe com todos os arquivos em um só.
Porém travei aqui nesta parte, como posso fazer isso?
Estou tentando usar a biblioteca urllib, porém sem sucesso.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve

url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/video.udacity-data.com/topher/2018/November/5bf32290_turnstile/turnstile.html'

#Criação da variável page com URL no método request.get
page = requests.get(url)

#coleta,analisa e configura como um objeto BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a')

#retorna os todos os links do Junho de 2017 da página

totalArquivos = 0
for link in links:
    href= link.get('href')
    if href != None and '1706' in href:
        totalArquivos += 1

print(totalArquivos)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Resposta atualizada:21/05/19**

```
url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/video.udacity-data.com/topher/2018/November/5bf32290_turnstile/turnstile.html'

#Este método retorna um objeto Response  
page = requests.get(url)
if req.status_code == 200:
    print('Requisição bem sucedida!!!')
    content = page.content
else:
    print("ATENÇÃO ERRO DO TIPO:",page)

#aqui usamos o método soup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('a')
totalArquivos = 0
for link in links:
    href= link.get('href')
    if href != None and '1706' in href:
        totalArquivos += 1


#Realizando o download dos arquivo

    insira o código aqui
        filename = href.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
        print("Iniciando o download do arquivo %s" %(filename))   
        print("Foi baixados o %s" %(totalArquivos),"arquivo")
        urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo Feedback! Caso a minha resposta tenha lhe ajudado com a sua pergunta, marque-a como correta. Recomendo dar uma lida na nossa Central de Ajuda, sobre [Como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Após isso, por favor, faça uma nova pergunta com essa dúvida e delete esta resposta. Nossa filosofia é limitar uma pergunta à um só escopo.

Comment: No caso, você deveria imprimir a variável `href`, ou adicionar os links (`href`s) numa lista.

Answer (score 1):

Você não está utilizando `urllib`, pelo menos não na prática. Você apenas o importou e não vi utilização dele em código algum do programa. Pelo contrário, vi um código escrito

```py
requests.get(url)
```

Que significa que você está tentando usar o módulo `requests`. No caso, modificando levemente o código consegui executá-lo sem problemas.

Eu apenas apaguei os imports do `urllib` e importei o módulo `requests`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/video.udacity-data.com/topher/2018/November/5bf32290_turnstile/turnstile.html'

#Criação da variável page com URL no método request.get
page = requests.get(url)

#coleta,analisa e configura como um objeto BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a')

#retorna os todos os links do Junho de 2017 da página

totalArquivos = 0
for link in links:
    href= link.get('href')
    if href != None and '1706' in href:
        totalArquivos += 1

print(totalArquivos)
```

---

#### Com o `urllib`:

Para utilizar o módulo que você já está tentando usar, você pode usar apenas a função `open()` (a qual você já está importando) e ler a resposta com o método `.read()`. Para isso, do seu código original, modifiquemos apenas algumas linhas:

Isto

```py
page = requests.get(url)
```

se torna isto

```py
page = urlopen(url)
```

E no no lugar no `page.text` (que é do `requests` também) você deve utilizar `page.read()`. Ou seja:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(),'html.parser')
```

Comment: Você copiou de algum lugar?